# Why does SQLAlchemy not add tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that makes a DB with 2 tables:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String
import json
from datetime import datetime


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mainDB.db', echo=True)
meta = MetaData()
connection = engine.connect()

def dbInit():
    item = Table(
        'items', meta,
        Column('key', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('id', Integer),
        Column('name', String),
        Column('stock', Integer),
        Column('itemTags', String),
        Column('dateAdded', String)
    )

    sales = Table(
        'sales', meta,
        Column('key', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('id', Integer),
        Column('stock', Integer),
        Column('date', String),
        Column('reason', String)
    )
    meta.create_all(engine)
    print("Databases created.")
    return meta
```

However, when looking at it in SQLiteStudio, all I get is a grey screen and a message that reads: `Could not restore window 'sales (mainDB)'', because the table sales doesn't exist in the database mainDB.` (Same for Items)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The code works for me, assuming that you actually call the `dbInit` function.

Comment: Just curious because I could not find it on google (Or I did not look hard enough), Do you have to add something to it to actually make the tables? I just tried reading it right after I ran it and gave me a blank screen.

Comment: `Metadata.create_all` will create all the table registered with a `Metadata` instance.  In your code, it is being called, and if I call `dbInit()` the tables are created.  But your code does not call `dbInit`, it only defines it.

Comment: After I ran `dbInit()`, I tried to read it both in code and in SQLiteStudio but got nothing. I have an idea that might work, but I will need to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: You have set `echo=True` on the engine, so you should be able to see that the `CREATE TABLE` statements are being issued.